# Java: Access token with SHA512 and random salt - how to verify?

Tags: java, encryption

I have a question regarding my webservice.
I am using an access token for security and authentification purpose. I want to store this token encrypted in my database and the token will expire after 90 days. 
I am using a random salt and now I am facing this issue:
How can I verify that? I was thinking about storing the salt in the database as well, but if I would do that I have to receive the user_id as well to get the salt and encrypt the token again. (So the user is sending the token in the header and its not encrypted there)

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Comment: You have to store the salt.  Also, read about JWT tokens.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt the token? How is it generated -- do you have a shared secret that's used here?

Comment: HI Mick, I thought it would be better to encrypt the token again. I am using UUID and hash add some bytes with a own method with a static secret.

Comment: I'm probably not seeing the big picture here, but if you're only encrypting the token to protect against attacks caused by the user registry getting exposed, then wouldn't it be easier to dramatically limit the expiry time of the token?

Comment: Hi, I have an idea for my issue. What do you think about that: Limitation of the expiry time to 30 days. Use a refresh token method every month and change the secret I am using every month? Still not the best way to protect everything but maybe there is some change in the database. Perhaps I am worried to much about that, there is no username or password within the token and is stored in another database...

Comment: All you need of your token is for it to be large enough (say, 256 bits) and generated by a cryptographic RNG. That's a lot more secure than inventing some token-generation mechanism of your own.

Comment: Ok guys, I guess this would be the best option. I will implement it that way. Thanks to all of you